# how to add Chinese language support in miktex?

Tags: miktex

I am using 2.9.7 miktex (up to date) on windows 7.

[image]

I am trying to add Chinese language support shown as below although I cannot find where the options is. could someone please give a hint?

[image]

Comment: Have you installed [CJK language support](https://miktex.org/packages/cjk)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you. I am not sure. How to check if I installed CJK language support? The link seems to be just a description without download link. I also googled and got an unanswered [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65275/installing-mincho-font-for-miktex-2-9-on-windows-7)

Comment: Unfortunately for you there is a bug - [MiKTeX / Bugs / #2095 cjk-fonts package incomplete](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2095/)